Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr 1 2022 12:00:00:000AM' could not be parsed at index 19
I've date format like Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM and looking to convert it into 20220401 (yyyyMMdd).How can we convert the Date format
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSSa");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}

When run this code giving me below error
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM' could not be parsed at index 4
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:10)

EDIT-1
As per Basil Bourque suggestions, still below is not working
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM".replace( "  " , " " ) ;
        Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                DateTimeFormatter.
                ofPattern("MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSSa")
                .withLocale( locale ) ;
        
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}

Still the same error
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr 1 2022 12:00:00:000AM' could not be parsed at index 19


The question you ask in the title and first sentence is not related to the error you mention. Your snippet of code isn't converting to another format, it's simply trying to parse a date into one specific format and failing.

could not be parsed at index 19 - You have a period instead of a colon in the format pattern

you cannot expect that 12:00:00:000 matches hh:mm:ss.SSS - first is using : to separate seconds from milliseconds, while pattern is using .

BTW: LocalDateTime.parse("Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM [ ]d yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa", Locale.ROOT)) does work ( replace not needed )

Don't keep your dates in strings. Then you also won't need to from a string in one format to a string in a different format. If your date comes from a database, retrieve a LocalDate, OffsetDateTime or other appropriate date-time type depending on the data type in the database. If you need yyyymmdd for data exchange, use the built-in BASIC_ISO_DATE formatter.

Have you got two spaces after Apr? What happens when rhe day of the month is 10 or greater? If the number is space-padded (right-aligned), look imto format pattern letter p for how to parse it.

I wanted to close this question. It’s unclear from the question whether the original question that I called this one a dupe of, is the right one, but I found it more helpful to close as a duplicate than as "unclear",or "needs debugging details", which would also both be valid reasons in my most honest opinion.

tl;dr

Your defined formatting pattern fails to match your input, in multiple ways.
Always specify a Locale when parsing localized text.
Where possible, use only ISO 8601 standard formats to exchange date-time values textually.

SPACE character
You have two SPACE characters between your first two parts. Replace with a single SPACE.
 String value = "Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM".replace( "  " , " " ) ;

Alternatively, you may indicate an optional SPACE in your formatting pattern with square brackets: [ ].
COLON character
Your formatting pattern says to expect a FULL STOP (.) character between second and the AM/PM. But your input string has a COLON (:) there.
Change your formatting pattern to match your input.
Locale
Specify a Locale explicitly rather than implicitly relying upon the JVM’s current default.
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "US" ) ;  // In Java 19+, use `Locale.of`. 
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa");
        .withLocale( locale ) ;

The Locale specifies the human language and the cultural norms to be used in localization. This includes the spelling of the month name, and the use of punctuation.
Generating text
To generate text in your desired, extract a LocalDate to focus on the date without the time of day.
LocalDate ld = myLocalDateTime.toLocalDate() ;

Then define a formatter for your format.
No need to define a custom formatter in your case. Your desired formatter complies with the “basic” form of the ISO 8601 standard format that minimizes punctuation. Java provides a constant for that particular format: BASIC_ISO_DATE.
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;

Example code
    String input = "Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM".replace( "  " , " " ) ;
    Locale locale =new  Locale( "en" , "US" ) ;  // In Java 19+, use `Locale.of`. 
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa")
        .withLocale( locale );
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , formatter ) ;
    LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
    String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
    System.out.println( output ) ;

See this code run at Ideone.com.
ISO 8601
Avoid parsing text in custom formats, and avoid parsing localized text.
The international standard ISO 8601 defines clear, simple, reliable formats for exchanging date-time values as text. These are easily read by machine as well as by humans across cultures.
The java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing/generating text.
The ideal solution is to educate the publisher of your data about the benefits of using ISO 8601.
Your input should be: 2022-04-01T00:00.

Thanks Locale locale = Locale.of( "en" , "US" ) ; doesn't works with Java8?

@Prateek Then use an older technique for instantiating a Locale.

What makes you think it's a localization issue?

You have several errors in your DateTimeFormatter.

There are two spaces between the month and the day. That's why Java is giving you the following error:


java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM' could not be parsed at index 4


As @Basil has written in his answer, you better pass a Locale to parse correctly your date, since Apr won't be parsed if you're on a different system like the Italian one, for example, which accepts only apr.

Lastly, you have a colon (:) to separate seconds and milliseconds, while your value contains a dot (.).


This is the fixed version of your code:
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "Apr  1 2022 12:00:00:000AM";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM  d yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa", Locale.US);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}

Disclaimer: I made changes only to your DateTimeFormatter supposing that you would have to abide to this specific format. However, if you are constructing the values to parse, make sure to not add extra white spaces and use standard symbols to separate each group.

I was writing my answer with the space and dot error when @Basil posted his with only the Locale solution. I haven't been quick enough.

Will their date strings with 2 digit dates have one space or two? Apr 13 or Apr  13?

@SotiriosDelimanolis the formatter would still need two spaces regardless of the number of digits for the day (Apr  1 or Apr  11) if they need/want to abide by this format.

That's what I was getting at. If their dates take the form Apr  13, then your format will work. But if the 2nd space is meant to be an aligning mechanism and their dates actually end up like Apr 13 (single space), then your format won't work.

@Sotirios Delimanolis No, it's not a gimmick to make up for a missing digit. It works for both Apr  1 and Apr  13. Try it out at https://onecompiler.com/java/42kbe6jh5

It doesn't work for Apr 13 (single space separator). I'm saying we don't know how OPs string are formatted for non-single digit dates.

@SotiriosDelimanolis oh ok, I finally see your point. I can only base my answer on what is posted in the question. As I stated in my answer: " supposing that you would have to abide to this specific format". I assume that this (double space) is the format that they want/need to use (for whatever reason).

BTW an optional space in the pattern can be represented like "MMM [ ]d yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa"
